# Classic ASP XMLDom read Root Node Name

Tags: asp-classic, xml-parsing

I receive this xml text

```
<InsertProductsRequest>
    <ProductsContainer>
        <Product>
            <ProductCode>AB25E</ProductCode>
            <Description>Good Item bla bla...</Description>
            <Price>25.5</Price>
            <Currency>EUR</Currency>
            ......
            <ShippingService>DHL</ShippingService>
            <ShippingService>TNT</ShippingService>
        </Product>
    </ProductsContainer>
</InsertProductsRequest>
```

using Classic ASP and Microsoft.XMLDOM

how can I get the root node name, thus "InsertProductsRequest"

Thanks
Joe

Comment: assuming .NET (specifically, System.Xml)  - XmlDocument.ChildNodes[0].Name (or XmlDocument.FirstChild.Name - but I haven't explicitly used that one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [tagName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms760213(v=vs.85).aspx) property of the [documentElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms759095(v=vs.85).aspx).

```vb
'the string containing xml document
xml = "<InsertProductsRequest></InsertProductsRequest>"

Set doc = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DomDocument")
doc.loadXML xml

Response.Write doc.documentElement.tagName
```

Comment: with `Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DomDocument.6.0")` also `SelectSingleNode("/").firstChild.NodeName` works

Comment: well @Joe there are many different ways to achieve the same result. here's another one `SelectSingleNode("//").nodeName`